# WebStorm does not recognize npm module imports

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules, webstorm

For our web service we are creating a package (npm module). I been messing with the `files` and `exports` section of the `package.json` file and I can't see how to get my WebStorm IDE to recognize the import path correctly when importing the .js and .scss files.

Let me explain some more.

Here is the structure of our compiled npm module:

[image: The structure of our compiled npm module]

My issue is: WebStorm says this path is invalid to import when I try

```
import { Widget } from '@dev/test';
```

and I see this

[image]

NOW the odd thing is, it DOES compile and works when our services webpack runs, however the IDE says its not there unless I do

```
import { Widget } from '@dev/test/lib/index';
```

then the IDE says it's OK.

Now same goes for importing a SCSS file. Our goal is to have something like this in our services `index.scss`:

```
@use '~@dev/test';
```

but webpack throws an error unless I do it this way

```
@use '~@ibm-cloud/feedback/lib/index';
```

If I have to keep it that way, that's fine. But I want to at least fix the issue with the js import.

I tried using only `files`, or only using `exports` and vice versa, or both together but I seem to either break both or break one of the imports.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: *"and I see this"* Just a note -- this particular issue is reported by ESLint.

Comment: got ya, any advice? on it though, thank you

Comment: Sorry, not a JS/TS person myself, cannot advise on this one. **P.S.** Consider contacting WebStorm Support, right from within the IDE -- `Main Menu | Help | Contact Support...`